# Kendo Grid Column Sorting

Tags: sorting, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I want decimal column sorting in kendo ui grid. In the Above screen shot I need Salary column(Decimal values - values are bind in json string) sorting in either ascending or descending. I need this option in MVVM model. No need in MVC Architecture (No need c# code) Any one can help me please. Am new of this field. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining `salary` as `number` in you `DataSource.model`.

Ex: Instead of defining the model as (or not defining it):

```
schema  : {
    model: {
        fields: {
            Id       : { type: 'number' },
            Name:    : { type: 'string' },
            Salary   : { type: 'string' },
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Define it as:

```
schema  : {
    model: {
        fields: {
            Id       : { type: 'number' },
            Name:    : { type: 'string' },
            Salary   : { type: 'string' },
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Check the two grids in the following example (http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/H4U7D/), the first defines `Salary` as `string` while the second defines it as `number`. The second `grid` correctly sorts the data.

Comment: Thanks. But I need this values for sorting like 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 2.1, 2.3, 2.2, 2.7, 3.1, 2.6.1, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 3.1.1, etc., how this values are sorting.....